# Dynamically created elements all return the same index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically creating dropdowns in a table, and I'm trying to grab the index of the dropdown that triggered the event, like so:

```
$(".template").on('change', '.dataTypes', function () {
    var selectedDatatype = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    var ix = $(this).index(); // get this index

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost...",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            populateListDropdown("gs", ix, result.Result);
        },
        error: function () { },
        timeout: 120000
    });
});
```

This code, regardless of the dropdown I interact with always returns a 0 for the index and I'm not sure why.

HTML if it's helpful. The page has a single row loaded at startup, and additional are added via button click.

```
<table class="tblColumns">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="column">
                Select DataType :
                <select class="dataTypes"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index()` method returns index based on its siblings. Your all dropdowns are in seperate `td`. So all have same index.

You are looking for `tr` index not `select`. Try

```
$(this).closest('tr').index();
```

Answer (score 0):

For further reading, check out https://api.jquery.com/index/

*"If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements."*

In your HTML the  is the only element, hence always returning '0'.

As @Azim pointed out, if you use , it might work.